# Uniform convergence and boundedness of $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin kx}{k}$

Tags: real-analysis

Why is $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin kx}{k}$ uniformly convergent on $[\delta,\pi]$ for all $0<\delta<\pi$ from this [nice property of Fourier series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3672441/g-ny-sum-k-1n-frac-sin-kyk-x-in-0-pi-evaluate-lim-n-to-in)?

Furthermore, why is the partial sum $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\sin kx}{k}$ uniformly bounded for all $n$ and $x \in (0,\pi)$ as discussed in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777250/understanding-uniform-bound-for-partial-sum/2777270#2777270).

Comment: It is shown in the problem statement that uniform convergence on $[\delta, \pi]$ follows from the Dirichlet test since $1/k \to 0$ monotonically and uniformly (with no dependence on $x$) and $|\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx|   \leqslant 1/ \sin(\delta/2)$ for all $x,n$. Do you not know how the bound for $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx$ is obtained?

Comment: yes. and I do not know the Dirichlet test@RRL. I know Dirichlet test, but the version i know can only be used to test the convergence of a series, but not uniformly convergence\

Comment: Its an easy extension to uniform convergence. The series $\sum g_n(x) h_n(x)$ converges uniformly for $x \in D$ if $g_n(x) \to 0$ monotonically and uniformly for $x \in D$ and the partial sums $\sum_{k=1}^n h_k(x)$ are uniformly bounded for all $n$ and all $x \in D$.

Comment: ok thanks, how is the bounded obtained?

Comment: I get it, thank you.

Comment: Do you want the derivation of the bound on $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx$?

Comment: no, thank you, I got how to prove it. But I have a question about https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2777250/understanding-uniform-bound-for-partial-sum/2777270#2777270. how to get the bound for the first term?

Comment: thank you for your generous reply, but it seems that the bound depends on x, how to claim the uniform bound?@RRL

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107977/discussion-between-wonder-and-rrl).

Comment: I showed there is a  bound of the absolute value of the first sum that does not depend on $x$.  It is $\pi$ as shown in the last line.  $Mx < \frac{\pi}{x} x = \pi$.

Comment: but the second sum depends on x?@RRL

Comment: I also edited your question as this is really about the uniform boundedness of the sum for $x \in (0,\pi)$.  Hopefully this clears it up for you.

Comment: thank you for your generous help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for $x > 0$ we have $|\sin (nx)| \leqslant |nx| = nx$ and

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^M\frac{\sin (nx)}{n}\right| \leqslant \sum_{k=1}^M\frac{|\sin (nx)|}{n} \leqslant  \sum_{k=1}^M \frac{nx}{n} = Mx,$$

and since $M = \min(N, \lfloor \frac{\pi}{x}\rfloor)\leqslant \lfloor \frac{\pi}{x}\rfloor \leqslant \frac{\pi}{x}$ we get

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^M\frac{\sin (nx)}{n}\right| \leqslant \frac{\pi}{x} x = \pi$$

For the second sum in the linked question it was shown that

$$\left|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} \right| \leqslant \frac{1}{|\sin(x/2)|}\left(\frac{1}{N} + \frac{1}{M+1} + \sum_{n=M+1}^{N-1}\left(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right) \right) = \frac{2}{(M+1)|\sin(x/2)|}$$

For $z \in (0,\pi/2)$ we have the inequality $\frac{2z}{\pi} \leqslant \sin z < z$ and, thus, for $x \in (0,\pi)$ we have $\sin(x/2) \geqslant x /\pi$. Hence,

$$\frac{2}{(M+1)|\sin(x/2)|} < \frac{2\pi}{(M+1)x}$$

In bounding this sum we can assume that $M < N$ (otherwise there are no terms) and, hence, $M = \lfloor \frac{\pi}{x} \rfloor$ implying that $M \leqslant \frac{\pi}{x} < M+1$ and $\frac{1}{(M+1)x} < \frac{1}{\pi}$.

Therefore,

$$\left|\sum_{n=M+1}^N \frac{\sin nx}{n} \right| \leqslant\frac{2}{(M+1)|\sin(x/2)|} < \frac{2\pi}{(M+1)x}< \frac{2\pi}{\pi} = 2$$

Comment: thank you for your kindness and the nice proof

Comment: does this website have something called add friends? or follow?